# When I used to run the Appium page object model code, it showing error like "Can't locate an element by this strategy: Locator map:"

Tags: appium, appium-android

When I tried to run the Appium page object model code, it shows an error like

> "Can't locate an element by this strategy: Locator map:".

Sometimes the test case executes and sometimes it results in the above error.

Login.Java:

```
public LoginActions(){

    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(DriverClass.getDriver()), this.loginLocators);
}

public void loadLoginPage(String username, String password) {
    this.loginViscenario(username, password);

}

public void click() {
    this.clickActions();
}

private void loginViscenario(String uname, String pwd) {
    loginLocators.username.sendKeys(uname);
    loginLocators.password.sendKeys(pwd);
    //commonActions.sendKeys(loginLocators.username, uname);
    //commonActions.sendKeys(loginLocators.password, pwd);
    DriverClass.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

private void clickActions() {
    loginLocators.login.click();
    DriverClass.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

It is throwing errors randomly. It should run like normal and after giving proper xpath also, the view is not clicking.

Answer (score 0):

In your page object model you must add the element mentioning its Locator strategy.
Add following element in your page object model according to your requirement like email, password, button etc.

```
//you can use id, accessibility or xpath
@AndroidFindBy(id = "element id here")
private MobileElement button1;

@AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "element id here")
private MobileElement textInput1;

public void click() {
   button1.click();
}

public void enterEmail(){
    textInput1.sendKeys("emailId@abc.com"):
}
```